# React Native Testflight App and Youtube Data API

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, youtube-api, testflight

I have a react native app published on TestFlight and everything is working (no crashes or anything) but one of my pages generates content based on a YouTube request. When I am testing using expo on my device it works perfectly.

But after following the steps to release on TestFlight and installing the app on my phone via TestFlight the page doesn't show anything. I can't figure out why the YouTube API is just not working for TestFlight only.

[image]

I have entered an API Key and even set it to unrestricted, but still it doesn't work for TestFlight. Only works on expo when I am directly running it on a device.